# Bash/Windows/SVN - Resource Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: windows, bash, svn

I'm using the Linux Subsystem for Windows (or whatever that new, fancy Ubuntu/Bash terminal is called in Windows 10). I'm using it in my Windows VM, which I am using to test an application developed and stored in Subversion.

I should point out that using the regular Windows command line, everything works perfectly with absolutely 0 issues. I just prefer Bash.

Anyway, svn is properly installed, and I can do commands like "svn status", "svn add", etc, in the Bash terminal no problem. However, if I try doing an "svn update" or "svn commit", that's when the problem happens.

I get the following error message:

```
myname@DESKTOP-VF4GBEA:~/Documents/Project$ svn update .
Updating '.':
svn: E000011: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://some-url.com/trunk/Project'
svn: E000011: Error running context: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I'm unsure why this is happening from the Bash terminal and not the Windows command line. I have Windows Defender disabled, no firewall there. I'm running Windows 10 Creators Edition (the latest version) in a virtual machine using VMWare Fusion on Mac OS Sierra. I do have Norton/Symantec protection running on the Mac, but it doesn't show anything having blocked a connection.

Regardless, doing these commands from the Windows command line, as I said, work perfectly fine.

Comment: But I can access the network. Like I said, from the windows command line it works perfectly, no issues at all.

Comment: `svn status` and `svn add` are local commands only. Does `svn status --show-updates` work too?

Comment: Can you `ping some-url.com` from inside the Windows *VM*?

Comment: I can't seem to do that, even from the windows command prompt. However, from the same windows command prompt, I CAN get svn commands to work. I will add that it needs to use a VPN to make the connection, but the VPN is on my mac and it's on, and again svn commands work, and they won't if it wouldn't detect the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the answer. The svn URL I was hitting was actually configured via my hosts file in the windows vm:

```
123.45.6.789 some-url.com
```

This was done in the windows file: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. However, to get it to work in the Windows Bash Terminal, it needed to also be configured in /etc/hosts. That was the issue.

Ok, this is good to know. I guess the Bash/Windows thing uses all of its own configurations.